# SWIFT: How do I add hours to NSDate object

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I generate a NSDate object from string.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
let stringToDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateFromService) // 2015-07-20 12:00:43 +0000
```

I get this string value from webserver. I need to modify for personal device timezone. Want to add hours this stringToDate object but not work

```
var addHours : Int = 2 // 2 hours will be added
var newDate = stringToDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(addHours)
```

Comment: looks like you are adding 2 seconds not 2 hours. timeInterval is always in seconds. or you can use components of NSDate. add `Int = Hour *60*60`

Comment: you should use `NSDateComponents` to adjust date and time.

Comment: Yes , he is adding seconds. `NSTimeInterval` represent  seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. This is what's known as an [**"XY Problem"**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
You should be asking "How do I display a date string I get from a web server in the user's local time zone."

`NSDate` represents a date/time in an abstract form that does not contain a time zone. You convert it to a specific time zone for display. Do not try to add/subtract hours to an NSDate to offset for time zones. That is the wrong approach.

The correct answer is simple. Create a second date formatter and don't set it's timezone to GMT. It defaults to the user's local time zone.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateFromService) 

let outputDatedateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
outputDatedateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
//leave the time zone at the default (user's time zone)
let displayString = outputDateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
println("Date in local time zone = \(displayString)")
```

Comment: Your second-last line contains some Objective-C syntax :)

Comment: And was missing a semicolon.  :)

Comment: So it did. Thanks for catching that, and thanks nhgrif for fixing it.

Answer (score 15):

Use `NSCalendarComponents`:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(
    .CalendarUnitHour, // adding hours
    value: 2, // adding two hours
    toDate: oldDate,
    options: .allZeros
)
```

Using `NSCalendar` will account for things like leap seconds, leap hours, etc.

But as [Duncan C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31516493/2792531) points out, simply adding hours is definitely the wrong approach.  Two time zones won't always be separated by the same amount of time.  Again, this is something especially true when we take daylight savings into account.  (For example, the United States doesn't start/end daylight savings on the same days as Europe, and Arizona doesn't even *do* daylight savings).

Comment: You are generally right about using NSCalendar and friends. But: If "leap hours" refers to DST transitions,  that is only an issue for *days* and larger units, not for two hours. And leap seconds are generally ignored by Unix time, it does not make any difference if you use NSDateComponents or add an NSTimeInterval.

Comment: Hmm, yeah.  But there are other reasons for using `NSCalendar`.  It's ultimately more readable... and it gets you in the habit of doing it write so that when it comes to a point where it unquestionably *does* matter, you don't get it wrong.

Comment: Sure. I mainly wanted to point out that the argument "NSCalendar etc is necessary to account for leap seconds" is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3 you can use this function:

```
//get next date by adding hours func  

getNewDateAfterAddingHours(hoursToAdd:NSInteger, oldDate:Date) -> Int64 {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hoursToAdd, to: oldDate)
    return Int64((newDate?.timeIntervalSince1970)!)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing it more often, check out library called [SwiftMoment](https://github.com/akosma/SwiftMoment) (inspired by the same .js library), which allows you to do following (and much more!):

```
// Create date using moment library
let myDate = moment(myString)

// Add one hour
let dateWithAddedHour = myDate + 1.hours
```

Moment is a wrapper around NSDate instance, while Duration (which is what you get from Int.hours, Int.minutes etc.) wraps an NSTimeInterval value.

Implementing this should take you just a moment! (Pun intended).